# How to get \citeyearpar indexed with imakeidx

Tags: biblatex, citing, indexing, makeindex

I know there is a package indxcite which allows you to get \citeyearpar into the index, but I use the package imakeidx and don't want to change all the commands (e. g. \citeyearpar to \iciteyearpar). So, is there an easy way to get the same result with imakeidx? I only need an index of persons.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,style=authoryear,indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeindex[columns=2,title=Titelregister]
\makeindex[columns=2,name=personenregister,title=Index of Persons]
\makeindex[columns=2,name=sachregister,title=Index of Subjects]
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[personenregister]}
{\namepartfamily}
{\namepartgiven}
{\namepartprefix}
{\namepartsuffix}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Hursthouse.1999,
 author = {Hursthouse, Rosalind},
 year = {1999},
 title = {On Virtue Ethics},
 address = {Oxford}
}
@book{Foot.2001,
 author = {Foot, Philippa},
 year = {2001},
 title = {Natural Goodness},
 address = {Oxford}
}
@book{Thompson.2008,
 author = {Thompson, Michael},
 year = {2008},
 title = {Life and Action},
 address = {Cambridge}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

In her book \textit{Natural Goodness} \citeyearpar{Foot.2001} the author says this and that, which is very similar to what Hursthouse\index[personenregister]{Husthouse, Rosalind} says
\citep[see also][p. 1]{Thompson.2008}

\printbibliography

\printindex[personenregister]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a way it makes sense that `\citeyearpar` does not send anything off to the index: It only prints the year (the command does not even take `extradate` into account: try `\citeyearpar{knuth:ct:b}` and `\citeyearpar{knuth:ct:c}` from `biblatex-examples.bib` and compare that with `\autocite{knuth:ct:b}` and `\autocite{knuth:ct:c}`) and years are not indexed by `biblatex`.

Depending on what exactly you want to send to the index you can add

```
\ifciteindex
  {\indexnames{labelname}}
  {}%
```

or

```
\ifciteindex
  {\indexfield{indextitle}}
  {}%
```

or

```
\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
```

to the definition of `\citeyearpar` (which you can find in [`blx-natbib.def`, ll.](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/ca032db14c25fcad84a75ce5f43ba59c39ac69f2/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-natbib.def#L41-L47)). The first bit of code only indexes the 'primary name' (usually `author` or `editor` in that order), the second bit only indexes the title of the work, the last bit of code indexes the same things that a normal `\cite` command indexes, which usually comes down to primary name and title, but that can be changed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreport}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[natbib=true,backend=biber,style=authoryear,indexing=cite]{biblatex}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeindex[columns=2,title=Titelregister]
\makeindex[columns=2,name=personenregister,title=Index of Persons]
\makeindex[columns=2,name=sachregister,title=Index of Subjects]

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[personenregister]}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeyearpar}[\mkbibparens]
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifciteindex
     {\indexnames{labelname}}
     {}%
   \printfield{year}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Hursthouse.1999,
 author  = {Hursthouse, Rosalind},
 year    = {1999},
 title   = {On Virtue Ethics},
 address = {Oxford},
}
@book{Foot.2001,
 author  = {Foot, Philippa},
 year    = {2001},
 title   = {Natural Goodness},
 address = {Oxford},
}
@book{Thompson.2008,
 author  = {Thompson, Michael},
 year    = {2008},
 title   = {Life and Action},
 address = {Cambridge},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
In her book \citetitle{Foot.2001} \citeyearpar{Foot.2001}
the author says this and that,
which is very similar to what Hursthouse\index[personenregister]{Husthouse, Rosalind}
says \citep[see also][1]{Thompson.2008}

In her book \citetitle{Foot.2001} \parencite*{Foot.2001}

% often \parencite* gives better results than \citeyearpar
In his book \citetitle{knuth:ct:b} \parencite*{knuth:ct:b} \citeauthor{knuth:ct:b}

In his book \citetitle{knuth:ct:c} \parencite*{knuth:ct:c} \citeauthor{knuth:ct:c}

In his book \citetitle{knuth:ct:b} \citeyearpar{knuth:ct:b} \citeauthor{knuth:ct:b}

In his book \citetitle{knuth:ct:c} \citeyearpar{knuth:ct:c} \citeauthor{knuth:ct:c}

\printbibliography

\printindex[personenregister]

\end{document}
```

[image: Index of Persons with four entries]

Note that you don't have to write the title of `Foot.2001` again, you can just use `\citetitle{Foot.2001}`.

Similarly don't have to type the primary name of a work, you can just use `\citeauthor`.

Depending on the exact outcome that is desired, I often prefer `\parencite*` over things like `\citeyearpar`. The latter is really only there to give the year of publication. The former can be used to give a citation label that drops the author name (because the author was already mentioned or is implicit in what is written). Note that due to the `natbib` compatibility mode, `\citep*` behaves differently from `\parencite*` (while `\citep` and `\parencite` do the same at all times).

Comment: ah okay, thank you very much! also your clarifications concerning \parencite* are very helpful